# Return rows in an R dataframe where there is the max for each group based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a simple data frame with 2 columns

```
scenario    item   ROA
0 -10 0      A   6.0
0   0 10     A   2.1
0  10 20     A   3.0
0 -30 0      B   0.5
10 0  0      B   1.0
```

What I need is to create a way to be able to condition the scenarios for each item (only positive or negative) and return the row where there is the max value of ROA

For example if I condition A to use only scenarios positive and B to only negative I should get

```
    scenario    item   ROA
     0  10 20     A   3.0
     0 -30 0      B   0.5
```

the values on the scenario column are strings not numbers, but there is only one negative sign, so it can be checked with a condition if it contains the "-" sign.

the condition for being negative scenario is just that it has a negative char in the string, the condition for being positive is that it does not.

Here you can create some sample data

```
scenario    <- c("0 -10 0","0 0 10","0 10 20","0 -30 0","0 -30 0")
item <- c("A","A","A","B","B")
ROA <- c(6,2.1,3,0.5,1)

dfts <- data.frame(scenario=scenario, item=item, ROA=ROA )
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you stated that scenario column is of string type, can you please provide reproducible data, to avoid any confusion?  Where are your conditions for items stored?  i.e. which are positive which are negative or are these to be hard-coded?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I added more info and some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(dplyr)

dfts %>%
  filter((!grepl('-', scenario) & item == 'A') | 
           grepl('-', scenario) & item == 'B') %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  slice(which.max(ROA)) %>%
  ungroup

#  scenario item    ROA
#  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 0 10 20  A       3  
#2 0 -30 0  B       0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is just another approach:
I used `strsplit` function from base R which splits a string based on `sep` argument which here is a single white space `" "`. This function returns a list the same length as `x` where `ith` element of the list is the separated elements of `x[i]`. Here each elements of your `scenario` is of length `1`. Then I chose the second separated element and transformed it to numeric class:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dfts %>%
  filter(map2_lgl(scenario, item, ~ (.y == "A" & as.numeric(strsplit(.x, " ")[[1]][2]) > 0) |
                    (.y == "B" & as.numeric(strsplit(.x, " ")[[1]][2]) < 0)))

  scenario item ROA
1  0 10 20    A 3.0
2  0 -30 0    B 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option

```
subset(
  subset(
    dfts,
    (1 + grepl("-", scenario)) == match(item, c("A", "B"))
  ),
  ave(ROA, item, FUN = max) == ROA
)
```

gives

```
  scenario item ROA
3  0 10 20    A 3.0
4  0 -30 0    B 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dfts %>%
     filter(!str_detect(scenario, '-') & item == 'A'| 
        str_detect(scenario, '-') & item == 'B') %>% 
     group_by(item) %>% 
     slice_max(n = 1, order_by = ROA)
```